# Why did my ultimate cooldown go much higher for no reason?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was playing Karthus in an ARAM. I had 118 ability haste putting my ultimate on a cooldown of around 64 seconds. Near the end of the game, I cast my ult, but when I took a look at ability cooldowns, I saw my ultimate was ticking down from around 99 seconds instead of the 64 seconds I had seen every previous time I had used my ultimate at full build. I even moused over the ability to see the cooldown as displayed by the ability tooltip, and it stated the expected cooldown of ~64s.

Why did my ultimate gain an additional ~40 seconds of cooldown?

My build consisted of Liandry's Anguish, Rylai's Crystal Scepter, Ionian Boots of Lucidity, Cosmic Drive Void Staff, and Rabadon's Deathcap. I had an Elixir of Sorcery active, and my runes consisted of Dark Harvest, Cheap Shot, Eyeball Collection, Ultimate Hunter, Transcendence, and Gathering Storm. The enemy team had a Xayah, Malphite, Zilean, Viegar, and Brand. My team had a Kindred, Lucian, Teemo, and Jhin.

I did not sell any of my items. Once I had reached full build, I would purchase an Elixir of Sorcery every time I was able to purchase from the store. The amount of time between my deaths was not long enough to have the elixir fall off either.

Comment: Did you cast your ultimate while alive or dead? I doubt this would make a difference but maybe it would give some hint as to what could've happened.

Comment: @hyper-neutrino I do not recall if I was alive or dead when I did cast it last, but I remember that the cast did finish and was not interrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug that's been in the game for a very long time now that may be the cause of what you experienced. This bug is still not fixed at the time of writing this answer.

When you die and revive, immediately after respawning, your ability haste (CDR) is not immediately taken into account. This means that if you use a spell, it will be put on the full cooldown rather than the reduced cooldown it would normally have when it takes your ability haste into account.

In Vandiril's video, "6 Bugs that should be fixed", he explains what this bug is and how it works, using Karthus as an example due to his very high baseline ultimate cooldown.

Here's that video, timestamped at 0:47. The explanation and demonstration goes until 1:22:

It's very possible that the reason your ultimate went on cooldown for such a long time is because you used it immediately after respawning, and you endured the effects of this bug. To my knowledge, there are no other bugs in the game now or when you posted this question that would cause this issue.

Comment: It was a pretty long time ago, so I don't recall if I used my ult when I respawned or not, but I would say there is a pretty high chance I did. I will take this as closure for what happened that day lol.